# Link not redirecting in visual studio

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I am creating a basic website. I added some pages and linked them. I was able to redirect to the pages easily but I just rebooted mu computer and now the links don’t seem to work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu2qL.jpg)

Comment: Give the full path

Comment: Please post you code for better understanding of your issue. Just to be sure you can check it you can hard reload for clearing cache and then try. Thanks

Comment: I have added the image. If you can see.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is the wrong syntax

```
<a href="/file.html">file</a>
```

use this ✅

```
<a href="./file.html">file</a>
```

or ✅

```
<a href="file.html">file</a>
```

read more about how [file path](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) works